How to fix "TextEncoder is not defined" error in Jest tests?
I'm encountering a "TextEncoder is not defined" error while running my Jest tests for an Angular component.
Jest unit test cases throwing error -

ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined

My Jest Configuration:

{
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"]
  }
}


Jest strips out a bunch of Node.js globals, see e.g. https://mswjs.io/docs/faq/#requestresponsetextencoder-is-not-defined-jest
